# how to switch div's multiple contents with one button

Tags: javascript

I want to create a div that its content (text) will be changed every time you click on a button - but not as a toggle but as multiple text changes.

I have 14 sentences - I need only one sentence to be presented at the time. by clicking on a button it will present the next sentence and so on. after the 14th sentence, I want it to loop back to the first one.

do you have any idea how to approach it? 
all the similar posts I found were about how to toggle two different text - I need multiple.

A good example of what I need - check the footer of this [site](https://kayma.com/home-eng.html)

Comment: You can change the text of an element by changing its `innertext` attribute. e.g. `document.getElementById("textbox").innertext = "This is some new text"`

Comment: please try to set in your button click function 
`document.getElementById("textbox").innertext = Your_Sentences_Array[Math.floor(Math.random() * Your_Sentences_Array.length)];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EASY and QUICK and Pure JavaScript

```js
var cnt = 0;
function callMe(){
var Your_Sentences_Array = 

['Sentences1', 'Sentences2', 'Sentences3', 'Sentences4', 'Sentences5', 'Sentences6', 'Sentences7'];

var div = document.getElementById('idtxt');
div.innerHTML = Your_Sentences_Array[cnt];

cnt == Your_Sentences_Array.length-1 ? cnt = 0 : cnt++ ;
}
```

```html
<div id="idtxt"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="callMe()">Click for change</button>
```

Comment: I don't think the sentences are supposed to be random. I think OP wants to iterate through them.

Comment: this is great! 
exactly what I needed!

thank you! I appreciate it a lot :)

Comment: @nirshh5, please accept my answer as per StackOverflow policy https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for giving me point

Answer (score 3):

You can declare a number which represents the sentence number, increment it at the button click and display the `i`th sentence modulo sentences array length in order to have a *loop* effect. Like this:

```js
var sentences = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth'];
var senNum = 0;
var sen = document.getElementById('sen');

sen.innerText = sentences[senNum++]; // set initial sentence
document.getElementById('change').addEventListener('click', function(e) {

  sen.innerText = sentences[senNum++ % sentences.length];
});
```

```html
<div id='sen'></div>
<button id="change">Change</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you store the the texts inside an array?

```js
var text = [
  'The road goes ever on and on',
  'Down from the door where it began',
  'Now far ahead the Road has gone',
  'And I must follow if I can'
];

var button = document.getElementById('change-text');
var div = document.getElementById('my-div');
var textIndex = 0;

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  //Clear current text
  div.innerHTML = '';
  //Create new text node and add text from your array
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  var textnode = document.createTextNode(text[textIndex]);         
  p.appendChild(textnode);

  //Add text to the div                              
  div.appendChild(p);

  //If index is at the end of the array, cycle back to the beginning
  if (textIndex > text.length()) {
    textIndex = 0;
  } else {
    //Or just increment by 1
    textIndex += 1;
  }
});
```